# jQuery not evaluating the function via $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Im loading html in ".content" via $.post using datatype HTML. The loaded content has select 2 jquery plugin. When i load the page first time it works fine, the Select2 plugin gets executed but if i go back and load it again then i get error

```
TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

my code which loads the ajax is

```
(".body .content").on("click", ".process_record", function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        $.post(url, function(data){
            $(".body .content").html(data);
        },"html");
    })
```

The content which iam loading through $.post

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/plugins/select/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".select").select2();
</script>
```

some html.... and

```
<select name="bank_id" class="select" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="1">
  <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">Option</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content is loaded AFTER the javascript is initialized. If you put the script into a document ready, or sent it to the bottom of the page, it should work fine.